# How to allow to add property on object but stop Modifying set of properties on object

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty, seal

I have some global object ***CD*** and it has set of properties as follows:

```
window.cd = {
  config:{
    title:"..."
  }
  a:func..., 
  b:56,
  c:..
}
```

I want user to allow add properties to **cd** and **cd.config** but properties `cd.a, cd.b, cd.config.title` to be sealed (no modification allowed) .

***User should not be able to delete window.cd or these properties as well*** (Other properties he can delete or modify).

I tried with following:

```
window.cd.a.seal();
window.cd.b.seal();
window.cd.config.title.seal();
```

but it thrown following error:

> window.cd.config.title.seal is not a function

Comment: `Object.seal` is a function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal, `String.seal` is not (`window.cd.config.title` is a string)

Comment: So how to achieve my requirement I want to stop user to modify title.

Comment: You have to seal an object, not individual properties of it.  Also, sealing doesn't prevent changes in property value, it only keeps properties from being added or changed.  Perhaps you want to mark them non-writeable https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @JasonFetterly And how to prevent cd from deleting together with define property.

Comment: You can't prevent window.cd from being deleted unless you put it inside of another object - 'window' cannot be sealed.

Answer (score 0):

A quick sample making title unwritable

```
"use strict";
// Use strict mode or assignments to nonwritable properties silently fail

window.cd = {
  config:{
    title:'mytitle'
  },
  a:12,
  b:56
}

console.log(cd.config.title)
Object.defineProperty(cd.config,'title',{writable:false});
cd.config.title="Test";  // Fails, throws exception if Strict mode
console.log(cd.config.title)
```

Comment: Object.seal(cd.config) will prevent deletion of any config properties.